# How can you stop a redirection with Zombie.js

Tags: node.js, zombie.js

I'm using Zombie.js to resolve urls with multiple redirections. For some reason I want to be able to detect a certain type of redirection and then stop the processing (do not follow that redirection).

```
var browser = new Browser();
browser.on('redirect', function(request, response, redirectRequest){
  var redirectUrl = response.url;
  if (redirectUrl === 'http://www.example.com'){
     //Do something and stop the processing
  }
});

browser.visit(urlToLoad).then(function() {
    //Do something
});
```

I tried to add a pipeline handler and throw an error with `next()` but that didn't work because I couldn't detect the redirection that way. Is there something I can do to stop the browser for loading the page if I detect my redirection?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "stop". You can certainly detect the redirection on the pipeline with a helper variable. In my case, I have to detect if the redirect is to a login form, perform the login and then return to the original page. I've found a way mixing pipeline and event listener:

```js
let redirectedFrom = null;

Browser.extend(function(browser) {
  browser.on('redirect', function(request, response) {
    if (response.status === 302 && response.url === 'login_page')) {
      redirectedFrom = request.headers.get('referer');
    }
  });
});

const browser = new Browser();

browser.pipeline.addHandler(function(browser, request, response) {
    if (redirectedFrom !== null) {
      // do something interesting here
      redirectedFrom = null;
    }
    return response;
});
```

Now when I `browser.visit()` and get redirected to the login page, I can login and the `visit(redirectedFrom)`